# MultiAutoCompleteTextView setDropDownAnchor

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, dropdown, multiautocompletetextview

I want to set multiautocompletetextview cursor as the anchor for my multiautocompletetextview itself. I want it to look like sublime or notepad dropdown, which is responsible whenever the user change the cursor, how can I do that?

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownAnchor("");
```

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: hello, can somebody help me?